# PySpark efficient way N biggest elements

Tags: pyspark, max

[image: My dataset]
So I have to get the n (default 3) biggest elements from this dataset. How do I do this in PySpark in an acceptable manner? I know how to do it in Pandas, but I would like to know how it is done in PySpark efficiently, or if it can be done efficiently.
My first idea was to use greatest from pyspark.sql.functions like this

```
ls = []
cols = df_tmp.columns[:-1]
for j in cols:
        max_v = df_tmp.where(df_tmp["Variable"] == j).select(F.greatest(*[F.col(col) for col in cols]))
        ls.append(max_v.collect()[0][0])
return ls.max
```

But it seems to be a very bad approach, as it gives back the biggest value (0.984) and not the combination (Charlie, Foxtrot). Also I do not see how to get the second biggest value without rewriting the value in cell (Charlie, Foxtrot), which is a thing I thought you should not do in PySpark.

Thank you for reading this and especially to everyone who might answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could [union](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union) all columns from Alpha to Foxtrot to create dataframe with three columns (numeric value, Variable column, column name of value). Please have a look at the example below:

```py
import random
#creating a dataframe similiar to yours
columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
l = [[random.random() if c!=r else None for c in range(6)] for r in range(6)]
l = [x + [columns[i]] for i,x in enumerate(l)]

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+
|                  A|                   B|                   C|                   D|                  E|                  F| _7|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+
|               null| 0.37958341713258026| 0.31880755415785833|  0.8908555547489883|0.41632799280431776| 0.0729721304772899|  A|
|0.21814744903713268|                null|0.024393462170815394|  0.9940573571339111| 0.7841527980918188|  0.194722179975509|  B|
|  0.786507586894131|  0.9155528558183477|                null|  0.5782381547037391| 0.9714912596343181| 0.5446460767903856|  C|
| 0.9108497603580163|  0.5088891113970719| 0.35594300627798736|                null|  0.514258802933162|0.19317616393798986|  D|
|  0.193214269992123|  0.6259176088252493|  0.4425532657461867|0.050484163355697276|               null| 0.6594661109179668|  E|
| 0.5567272189587709|0.020606558131312402| 0.21905184240270814|  0.2817064382900445| 0.5409619970394691|               null|  F|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+---+
```

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

newdf = df.select(F.col('A').alias('value'), F.col('_7').alias('row'), F.lit('A').alias('column'))

for col in columns[1:]:
    newdf = newdf.union(df.select(col, '_7', F.lit(col)))

newdf.orderBy(newdf.value.desc()).show(3)
```

Output:

```
+------------------+---+------+
|             value|row|column|
+------------------+---+------+
|0.9940573571339111|  B|     D|
|0.9714912596343181|  C|     E|
|0.9155528558183477|  C|     B|
+------------------+---+------+
```